# How to find match and replace value in tab separated text file using Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a tab separated tsv file with header like below

[image]

In the **Manager** filed I wanted to be replace with **Primary Email** of Matching **ID** and **Manager** using PowerShell. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You can parse TSV files with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Import-Csv) ``-Delimiter "`t"``. I suggest you start there and, if you get stuck, update your question with what you've tried so far and where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you want, but here is some code to get you on the right track.

Use `ConvertFrom-Csv` to get a native object. Create a hashmap that maps `Id` to `Primary Email`, e.g. with input `infile.csv`:

```
ID      Source  Primary Email   Manager
A1      X       test@gmail.com  A2
A2      X       test1@gmail.com A4
A3      Y       test2@gmail.com A5
A4      Y       test3@gmail.com A6
```

Run this:

```
$d = gc infile.tsv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"

$h = @{}
$d | % { $h.add($_.id, $_."Primary Email") }
```

This gives you the data in `$d` and the hashmap in `$h`. Now replace the manager column with the corresponding email (where it exists), e.g.:

```
$d | % { if ( $h[$_.manager] ) { $_.manager = $h[$_.manager] } }
```

To get back to the original format use `ConvertTo-Csv`:

```
($d | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t") -replace '"',''
```

```
ID      Source  Primary Email   Manager
A1      X       test@gmail.com  test1@gmail.com
A2      X       test1@gmail.com test3@gmail.com
A3      Y       test2@gmail.com A5
A4      Y       test3@gmail.com A6
```